# What is the intent of this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I ran into the following:

```
DECLARE @UpdateDtm datetime = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE())))
SELECT @UpdateDtm
```

It returns today's date: `2021-10-11 00:00:00.000`, but I am not exactly understanding the logic.  First it deducts 10 minutes from `GetDate`, then it gets the difference in days between that and beginning of time.  Then it adds that difference (in days, once again) to the beginning of time.

From what I can tell, it could simply be replaced with `CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)`.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Correct, it could indeed be replace with `cast` in this case, but it is a generic formula for truncating to an arbitrary point

Comment: Well the -10 means that for the first 10 minutes of the day your result is still yesterday, so that can't be replaced by the cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention is to get the date for at midnight to the time 10 minutes ago. So for (roughly) now, `2021-10-11T22:30:30` (UTC) this would return `2021-10-11T00:00:00`. If, however, it were `2021-10-11T00:07:30` it would return `2021-10-10T00:00:00`.

Why it doesn't just `CAST`/`CONVERT` to a date, I am not sure. Perhaps it was written before 2008 initially?

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(minute,-10, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Before DATE was introduced this was one of the patterns to truncate the time portion of a datetime.  The other being a cast through varchar truncating the time portion of the string .

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  this is why I stated *"Perhaps it was written before 2008 initially?"*